# Download folder for GetHTTP in Apache Nifi

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, apache-nifi

Where is the download folder for GetHTTP processor in Apache Nifi? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no download folder per se.  When content enters NiFi through a GetHTTP processor, it is created as an item in the content repository with a FlowFile pointing to that particular content claim for framework purposes.  If you wanted to save this content to some place outside of NiFi's repository, you could make use of the [PutFile](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutFile/index.html) processor to save it to a location of your choosing through PutFile's configuration options.

Comment: No problem! Feel free to reach out to the community if you have any other questions.